# retrieve thread context java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, executorservice

Perhaps it's simple to do but I don't know how to.

First I have class A which creates one or more class B(Runnable) with an Executor.
Each class B must do some tasks, but I want to know when each thread has finished.

```
Class A {
   private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
   private int nbThread=3;
   public A(){
      scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(nbThread);
   }

   public start(){
      for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; i++) {
          scheduler.execute(new B();
      }
  }
```

}

```
Class B implement Runnable {

    public B(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.printl("test");
    }
```

}

Now what I want is to do others tasks only when those 3 threads print each one (system.out.println("test")
If thread number one doesn't finish then we do anything.
I'm not very strong in java, so I need some help.
thanks

Comment: have you tried out [joins?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

Comment: no, you think it's good solution? i'm looking about Future, any idea? thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you might want to look at is [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface in java concurrent package.

I updated your `start` method to give you an example of how to use it.

```
public void start() {
    Future<?>[] futures = new Future[nbThread];

    for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; i++) {
        futures[i] = scheduler.submit(new B());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; i++) {
        try {
            futures[i].get(); // waits until the current B is done, and then just returns null
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // All futures now finished executing
}
```

---

Update: An alternative solution if you always want to wait until all task are done is to use [`ExecutorService.invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)). Like in the following example (note that I changed `B` to implement `Callable`.

```
class A {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private int nbThread = 3;

    public A() {
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(nbThread);
    }

    public void start() {
        List<Callable<Object>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        callables.add(new B());
        callables.add(new B());
        callables.add(new B());
        try {
            scheduler.invokeAll(callables); // blocks until all B finished executing
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // All B's now finished executing

    }
}

class B implements Callable<Object> {

    public B() {

    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: so i'm asking question: how to know that each futur  is executed? if i have another method executeTeskAfterAllThread(), how to know if all running thread are executed?

Comment: future.get() waits until the future is executed. so every iteration in the last loop waits for the current B to finish executing. that means that after the loop (added comment) all futures are done

Comment: If you think this answers your question, you can also mark this as the correct answer (so I will get some more reputation points :) )

Comment: Here is a link that shows and explains it easier how to accept an answer than I can write as a comment :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work